# PHP expecting double colon

Tags: php, wordpress

I am by no means fluent in PHP or really any language for that matter. However, my companies website is down and at the moment I'm the most knowledgeable Webdev onsite(ha).

When navigating to the site I get this message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" followed by the file and line the error is in. I have found that it is expecting a double colon somewhere in this line:

```
if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || empty( DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_die( esc_html__( 'You do not have permission to optimize images.', EWWW_IMAGE_OPTIMIZER_DOMAIN ) );
```

However, I have no idea where. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show the full error message. (with file and line).

Comment: Show the lines before. With errors such as this, it's often because something is missing before the referenced line.

Comment: @aynber you need to show exact error and more code, as sometimes line number is incorrect because starting `(` can be much before in the file.